# How can I enter the trade without waiting for candle closing in Pinescript Strategy?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, strategy-pattern, candlestick-chart

I have a strategy based on rsi , macd , ema and ADX. I trade with small profit rates. But when the conditions are met, it enters the trade at the close of the candle. I want it to be processed as soon as the conditions occur, like an indicator. How can I do this with codes?

My transaction is reversed because the candle is waiting for the close in the image. How can I make the changes to be processed as they are created?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that on historical bars because only the OHLC information is saved on the historical bars.

For real time trading, you can set `calc_on_every_tick` argument of the `strategy()` to `true`.

> ***calc_on_every_tick (const bool)*** Specifies whether the strategy should be recalculated on each realtime tick. If true, when the
> strategy is running on a realtime bar, it will recalculate on each
> chart update. If false, the strategy only calculates when the realtime
> bar closes. The argument used does not affect strategy calculation on
> historical data. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's
> "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. The default is false.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you mentioned is valid only for " exit " . I'm talking about opening a transaction.

I mentioned using the "once per bar" feature as in the indicator.